# Does Process Builder run with System permissions or User permissions?

Tags: permissions, process-builder, field-level-security

Regarding field-level security, does Lightning Process Builder run as system-level permissions or user?  That is:

- Can I trigger an update to a field that the current user cannot edit?
- Can I filter based on a field the current user cannot read?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000DQWRAA4):

> Process Builder runs in the system mode so the object and field level
>   permissions both will be ignored for the user who triggers the
>   Process.

Comment: I am trying to resolve a problem surrounding this, here:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170497/lock-out-record-from-user-edit-but-allow-process-builder-edits  ... namely, how to identify in a VALIDATION RULE that it's Process Builder running so a bypass can be set.

Comment: I don't think this answer is true. Processes built in Process Builder run as the User who triggered it. I've tried and tried and even seen this Idea Post on Salesforce IdeaExchange. `https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dx9sAAC`

Comment: Sure, the process runs as the user, but permissions are system-like. Like if the user doesn't have access to a field the process updates, the process will update it anyway and the "last modified by" will be set to that user anyway (thus ignoring permissions).

Comment: That doesn't seem to apply when the user is REST Guest User. When the process is triggered by record change or platform event initiated by an API call through a REST site (guest user context), the process throws an error (citing REST Guest User context) when trying to post to Chatter, and just does nothing if you try to fire a Custom Notification.

Answer (score 5):

Process Builder always runs in System  context and hence you can edit the record or read the record even if user does not have access to the same .

Answer (score 3):

1. System mode: – In which the object and field-level permissions of the
   current user are ignored.
2. User mode: – In which the permissions, field-level security, and
   sharing rules of the current user are enforced.
3. Flow runs in user mode.
4. Process Builder runs in system mode. When you launch a Flow using
   the Process Builder, then it will run in system mode.

Comment: Actually, as of April 25, 2021, I realized flows don't ignore user permissions.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: If your Process Builder calls a Flow, and that Flows uses an Invocable Method (Apex), and the user doesn't have access to the apex class that houses the Invocable Method, the Flow will error. Make sure the profile/permission set of the user has the class added to Enabled Apex Class Access.