# Process Builder user has write access to read only field

Tags: profile, process-builder, flow, field-level-security

We have a process built with Process Builder, that updates a customer field on Account from a related object. When the related object is created, it copies a date from the related object, to a date field on the account.

Some accounts are not getting updated properly, which got me digging. I found that the users who are executing the update on the related object are assigned a security profile with Read Only access to the field on the Account object. However, when I log in as one of those users, the process updates the read only field with no problem.

I checked the effective permissions on that field, and it does indicated that profile has read only access.

I also enabled change tracking on that field and it shows the user with the read only access to that field made the change.

I checked for any permissions sets that might be enabling write access to that field, and there are none.

So how can a user, whose security profile has read only access to a field, execute a process that updates that field?

Comment: Is the Read Only access through the Page Layout or through FLS?  If it's through the Page Layout, that only restricts the UI.  If it's through the FLS then it looks like it may be a bug in Process Builder.

Answer (score 5):

Your question has already been answered [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/124122/does-process-builder-run-with-system-permissions-or-user-permissions).

> Process Builder runs in the system mode so the object and field level
>   permissions both will be ignored for the user who triggers the
>   Process.